# Can use DB Browser program with my application database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, flutter

I'm facing some problems dealing with the database and I want to keep track of the elements in the database if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i didn't understand, i haven't install it yet in my phone on debug
>   mode

If the phone isn't rooted and you've stored the database in the default location (most likely), then it will be in a protected area and cannot be directly accessed. If the phone has been rooted then you'd have access.

However, typically you'd use an emulator to develop an App rather than a real device (e.g. Android Studio's build in emulator or perhaps GenyMotion) and access to the databse is then generally possible via clicking on **Device Explorer** from within Android Studio e.g. :-
[image]

After clicking click on the **data** folder and then click on the **data** folder within the dta folder and then find the folder that equates to the package (as per your App) and then click on that. There would be a **databases** folder and the database file will be the file that is named exactly the same as the database  e.g.

[image]

- the package for the database in the example screenshot (not the same as the former App to reduce the screen size) is **aaa.so553322709simpleloggingexample** and the datbase name is **mydb** (as this is on Android Pie and that the database is using the default WAL mode then the -shm and -wal files also exist).

You can right click on the database file and then on Save-As to save the file on the PC. You can then open the file with your SQL Management Tool (e.g DB Browser).

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to mention that I'm using flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can access to db file of your application in Device File Explorer.
data-->data-->your app package name-->databases
then save as it and see it in DB browser.
Also you can pull db file with adb

Comment: i didn't understand, i haven't install it yet in my phone on debug mode, can't i find that database in my pc ?